# Can't get this code to work

Tags: bash, shell

I'm writing a bash shell script that uses a case with three options:

1. If the user enters "change -r txt doc *", a file extension gets changed in a subdirectory.
2. If a user enters "change -n -r doc ", it should rename files that end with .-r or .-n (this will rename all files in the current directory called *.-r as *.doc)
3. If the user enters nothing, as in "change txt doc *", it just changes a file extension in the current directory.

Here's the code i produced for it (the last two options, i'm not sure how to implement):

```
#!/bin/bash

case $1 in 
 -r)
  export currectFolder=`pwd`
  for i in $(find . -iname "*.$2"); do 
   export path=$(readlink -f $i)
   export folder=`dirname $path`
   export name=`basename $path .$2` 
   cd $folder
   mv $name.$2 $name.$3
   cd $currectFolder
  done
  ;;
 -n) 
  echo "-n"
  ;;
 *)
  echo "all"
esac
```

Can anyone fix this for me? Or at least tell me where i'm going wrong?

Comment: What doesn't work about the code?

Comment: @John, when i ran it yesterday (currently not near a linux computer), the -r won't rename the file extension. The "-n" (2) and "*" (3) options, i'm not sure how to code. I need help with that.

Comment: @Mr Teeth: you are talking about any files with a particular extension in the respective locations? One thing I don't really understand is the `-n -r` ...

Comment: -n and -r is the argument it takes. So if you enter "change -r txt doc *" (notice the -r) it does this: "a file extension gets changed in a subdirectory." If you enter "change -n -r doc" (notice the -n) it does this: "rename files that end with .-r or .-n (this will rename all files in the current directory called *.-r or *.-n as *.doc)".

Comment: @Mr Teeth: the proper way would be to follow the GNU standard of parsing command line switches ;) ... use `--` to separate switches from file names. Working on a little version that will at least get you started.

Comment: @Mr Teeth: check out my answer. Let me know if anything is unclear ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should brush up on are string substitutions. All kinds of them actually. Bash is very good with those. Page 105 (recipe 5.18) of the Bash Cookbook is excellent reading for that.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Make it more flexible for improving command line parsing later
SWITCH=$1
EXTENSIONSRC=$2
EXTENSIONTGT=$3

# Match different cases for the only allowed switch (other than file extensions)
case $SWITCH in
 -r|--)
  # If it's not -r we limit the find to the current directory
  [[ "x$SWITCH" == "x-r" ]] || DONTRECURSE="-maxdepth 1"
  # Files in current folder with particular pattern (and subfolders when -r)
  find . $DONTRECURSE -iname "*.$EXTENSIONSRC"|while read fname; do
    # We use a while to allow for file names with embedded blank spaces
    # Get canonical name of the item into CFNAME
    CFNAME=$(readlink -f "$fname")
    # Strip extension through string substitution
    NOEXT_CFNAME="${CFNAME%.$EXTENSIONSRC}"
    # Skip renaming if target exists. This can happen due to collisions
    # with case-insensitive matching ...
    if [[ -f "$NOEXT_CFNAME.$EXTENSIONTGT" ]]; then
      echo "WARNING: Skipping $CFNAME"
    else
      echo "Renaming $CFNAME"
      # Do the renaming ...
      mv "$CFNAME" "$NOEXT_CFNAME.$EXTENSIONTGT"
    fi
  done
  ;;
 *)
  # The -e for echo means that escape sequences like \n and \t get evaluated ...
  echo -e "ERROR: unknown command line switch\n\tSyntax: change <-r|--> <source-ext> <target-ext>"
  # Exit with non-zero (i.e. failure) status
  exit 1
esac
```

The syntax is obviously given in the script. I took the freedom to use the convention of `--` separating command line switches from file names. This way it looks cleaner and is easier to implement, actually.

**NB:** it is possible to condense this further. But here I was trying to get a point across, rather than win the obfuscated Bash contest ;)

PS: also handles the case-insensitive stuff now in the renaming part. However, I decided to make it skip if the target file already exists. Can perhaps be rewritten to be a command line option.

Comment: Thanks SAD, but your code is to complicated. You have to understand i'm still a novice at bash shell script. Is there a simpler way I can implement this? Here's an old code that I wrote, which is similar to it. Can you implement what i'm trying to do in it? #!/bin/sh

#  $1 extension to be renamed 
#  $2 to the new extension name

EXTf=$1
EXTt=$2

while test Z$3 != Z
do
    NAME=$3
    echo $NAME
    new=`basename $NAME .$EXTf`
    echo $new
    mv $new.$EXTf $new.$EXTt
    shift
done

Comment: Give me your email address, let me explain what i'm trying to do better.

Comment: @Mr Teeth: sorry, won't give it in an open location like this. What's so complicated about the code? Should I comment it even more? It's not a problem, but I thought you'd know the basics.

Comment: @SAD, thanks a lot for adding the extra comments, I can understand what you're trying to do now. The last version was a but complicated. This is much clearer. Don't worry about the email thing. Is there a private messaging system on here?

Comment: @Mr Teeth: don't think there is a PM facility, though it would be very cool. Glad it works for you now. If you have questions about some parts of the script, just ask.